# how to rerender the tab from commanbutton in another tab

Tags: visualforce, rerender, commandbutton, tab

I have a custom tabpanel with 8 tabs and i have a button in tab 3 which will trigger an action to update the info in tab 2.

```
<apex:tabPanel id="theTabPanel" switchType="client" selectedTab="tTab1" styleClass="theTabPanel">
<apex:tab label="Tab 1" id="tab1">
content
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="Tab 2" id="tab2">
content
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="Tab 3" id="tab3">
content
<apex:commandButton  value="Copy Info to Tab2" action="{!copyInfo}" reRender="tab2" />
</apex:tab>
```

but the reRender doesnt work. nothing happen when i click the button

Comment: Are you expecting the rerender to also somehow switch it to display that tab?

Comment: i dont need to switch to display the tab, just 'refresh' tab2 with updated information.

Answer (score 0):

Apex Command button can invoke javascript on Oncomplete. so call a javascript method and switch tabs.

oncomplete is an attribute on command Button

oncomplete  String  The JavaScript invoked when the result of an AJAX update request completes on the client.

oncomplete="switchtabs();"

function switchtabs() {
//logic goes here
}